# How is it possible to use object "angular" even if 'use strict' statement is used?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gulp, jshint

I’m using the gulp-jshint which makes me add ‘use strict’ directive in every file and therefore I can’t use my global object emApp, defined in my app.js file like this:

```
var emApp = angular.module('emApp');
```

However, I see that jshint says nothing about angular object. I’d like to know why is that and how to do the same thing with my own emApp object.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking here.  `use strict` does not prevent one from declaring variables and does not prevent the angular Javascript from defining the `angular` variable.  It sounds like you may be confused about what `strict` mode does.  You can read a summary here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode

Comment: @jfriend00 you should post that as an answer

Comment: @DanPantry - it's hard to post an answer when you don't really understand the question.  Yes, I think the OP is confused about strict mode, but I don't really know what they're asking.

Comment: @DanPantry I've tried to clarify my question. I hope you understand now what I'm asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two options to tell JSHint about global variables:
1)  If you want to tell about the globals in the particular file, use this directive in the beginning of the file:

```
/* globals myVariable: false */
```

2)  If you want to declare global for all files in your project, you can add this directive in .jshintrc file, like this:

```
"globals": {
   "myVariabe": true
}
```

More about globals with JSHint read here: http://jshint.com/docs/

P.S. angular object mentioned in the question was defined in .jshintrc file

Answer (score 2):

With `'use strict'` you have to assign either to `this.emApp` (on top level) or `window.emApp` (works within functions too), no `var` is needed.

Though the purpose of every modular approach (and Angular's too) is to minimize the usage of global variables, so doing

```
/*jshint browser: true */
/*global angular */
'use strict';

var emApp = angular.module('emApp');
```

in every place where you use the module is a good thing.

Comment: better yet, you could use the commonjs pattern through webpack and export the angular module as a commonjs module. that way you don't have to repeat the name everywhere

Comment: It doesn't explain why global angular object is ignored by jshint.

Comment: @zhekaus Use `/*global angular */`, I've updated the answer for jshint.

Comment: I’ve found another answer.
To make jshint ignore any global variable you have to add this variable into .jshintrc file like it was done for angular object, into section "globals":

        ...
     "globals": {
      "angular": false,
      "emApp": false
     }
    }